# How to attach process using Instruments on macOS Catalina?

Tags: node.js, instruments, macos-catalina

I want to use Instruments tool with "Allocation" template for Node.js add-on on macOS Catalina. When I try to attach to running Node.js process, I get this error:

```
Failed to attach to target: Failed to attach to target process.
```

I guess that this is about new process memory protection system. How to bypass it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't unless it's Xcode 11.4 beta 3 and iOS 13.4 sim (or later).

Apple hosed us!